# which is better for me qt or VS I am begginner

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2013

I am the beginner in programming and from last year I started programming. And I done with C and learning the C++ and I also study the HTML. Now I want to try hand on Software programming which is better for me QT or Visual Studio for developing the commercial or non-commercial software.

Comment: See related topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445113/qt-or-mfc-which-is-better-to-learn?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Qt is an [application framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_framework), whereas Visual Studio is an [Integrated Development Environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) (IDE). They are not the same thing, so you can't compare them.

In addition, please note that questions that ask for comparisons and generate a lot of personal opinions do not find favour in this forum.